# How can I use google to find all unknown webpages point to one specific known web page?

Tags: html, google-search

It's easy to find all children pages of one webpage. But it is not trivial to get all parent pages of one webpage, how can I do that by using Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't and Google cannot help you as it doesn't index all of the web. 
At best it follows links on other pages, or is initiated by someone wanting to have something indexed explicitly.

Create a server. Put an HTML page on it that no other page on your server has a link to. Name the page with some non-guessable UUID in the name.
Google will not find this unless they start to randomly change parts of URLs to test for existing pages (a lengthy process).

Within that page you can have links pointing to other pages. It is a parent page for those pages, is a web page, and will not be found via Google.

Comment: If I can not find all the pages, how can I at least find those indexed by Google? Are there tutorials out there?

Comment: @user54369 You can just search for a URL (part) in google. Do your really need a tutorial for that? Go to google.com, type the URL(part) in the input box and press [Google Search] (or have selenium do that programmaticallly for you). Alternatively use the [custom search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)